# Save phonegap captured images to parse

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, cordova

I'm trying to save the photo captured using Phonegap's camera API. The function returns the file uri. When I save this, it directly saves the string uri and not the file.
I even tried specifying the content type as image in ajax header file. Gives me a broken link.

```
function capturePhoto(){
    //alert(address);
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,onFail,{sourceType:1,quality:60,destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
}

function uploadPhoto(data){
    var serverUrl = 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/myphoto.jpg';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id': PARSE_APP,
        'X-Parse-REST-API-Key':PARSE_REST
        // "Content-Type": "image/png"
    },
        url: serverUrl,
        data: data,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(e){
            console.log(e.url);
        },
        error:function(){
            console.loh("ERROR");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use `destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.Native_URI`. This will return the image's actual location on the device, typically something like `file://storage/0/sdcard/...`. You can then use this location to load/send/manipulate the image.

Comment: That's exactly what I have done. But I'm not able to send the image just using its location. Should I convert it to base64 or a file object and then upload. If yes, how to create a file object using uri in javascript.I've been stuck on this for really long now.

Comment: @user3646217 Oi sorry I typed the wrong one. I meant Native_URI

Answer (score 0):

You need the [FileTransfer API](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/blob/master/doc/index.md) to get the contents of the file.  In your uploadPhoto callback insert the following:

```
function uploadPhoto(data){
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();

    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.params = { // Any params you need...
    };

    ft.upload(data, 'https://api.parse.com/1/files/myphoto.jpg',
        function (e) {
            console.log('Success');
        },
        function (e) {
           alert("Upload failed");
        }, options);
}
```

You might need to change some of the options and parameters depending on your backend (which you have not specified).  Christopher Coenraets has a good [video tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/how-to-upload-pictures-from-a-phonegap-application-to-node-js-and-other-servers-2/) with code on how to do this. The other solution is base64 the result, in this you set the src of a image that you create to be the fileUri and then draw the image onto a canvas and get the dataUrl of the canvas.  This method works with older versions of PhoneGap but is considerably slower than directly uploading using FileTransfer API.

Comment: So the thing is, the 1st option you suggested wouldn't work with Parse RESTAPI. Read (https://www.parse.com/questions/file-upload-returns-201-but-doesnt-seem-to-be-valid)

And for the second option I don't need to convert it using canvas element because phonegap itself lets me do that, just by setting Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL. The problem is even after getting the base64 encoded string how to store it to parse in form of a png file?

Comment: @user3646217 The last time I needed to store dataUrl's in Phonegap they didn't have the DATA_URL option, so that's a nice new feature.  I think your question is then more of a Parse question, which I have never used.  If you control the backend you can easily convert a dataUrl to a file by stripping of the dataUrl wrapper and base64 decoding the results, however I haven't used parse before but a little googling and find this: https://www.parse.com/questions/export-html5-canvas-image-to-parse-through-rest-api-or-javascript-sdk which may do what you need.